# How to pick same extension files on subfolders, using TFS?

Tags: tfs, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-build-task

In the release definitions on TFS, using the archive task, I have many subfolders, that may or may not have subfolders inside them, I want the task to archive only same extension files.

To help you understand the issue:

```
archives:
  index:
    items:
      showcase.txt
    test:
      list.txt
  targeting:
    names:
      clients:
        old:
          men:
            status.txt
```

My goal here is to zip every ".txt" file, no matter where the file is in the structure.

I tried the wildcards and it looked like this: 
archives/**/*.txt

It didn't work.

Comment: Which version of TFS, can you share a screenshot of the task you're using? (even if it's a link to a picture elsewhere, i can edit it into your post. Have you tried using a copy task to create a file structure to archive that contains just the files you're after?

Comment: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/347019/zip-files-build-task-fails-when-zipping-many-files.html?inRegister=true

Comment: The issue is very similar in this link I posted, the error messages are the same at least.

Comment: Can you edit your question to include the tfs version (in the tag) and the actual error messages you are seeing?  Taht way others that want to help, won't have to piece it together every time. It also helps search for others with the same issue later.

Comment: A screenshot or an overview of the exact configuration of the task helps as well.

Comment: I worked around this, by copying the files to a new location, and after that, I used the archive task.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I worked around this, I was able to get the files I wanted by copying these files to a new location, and after that, I used the archive task to create a zip file containing only the needed files.